# Displaying people picker as 'name with presence' in Nintex display form

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

I need help with displaying people and groups as Name with Presence in Nintex Display forms, instead of displaying their names followed by some random text (ID, email ID, etc)[image]

I want only the name to be displayed in the form instead of all these random characters.

Answer (score 0):

There is a client side api to work with the people picker control. You can find information about it here https://community.nintex.com/docs/DOC-1222. Hope that helps.